# AVAudioPlayer is not working properly in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, avaudioplayer

The audio player code that is working finely in the IOS 4.3  is not working in IOS 5.

Works fine in the simulator, but no sound from the device. Sometimes sound can be heared for a while and sfter few seconds the sound will stop.

No errors are found. IS this the problem with IOS 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it worked when I used to change my line of code with ARC enabled. I just customized the release method, and it worked.

Comment: could you elaborate? I'm not sure what this sentence means (and I have a similar sound issue)

Comment: nah, I think Cyupa has the answer in this page... :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple audio/video players/recorders in your app, you should try specifying what type of audio session will begin. If you don't, the first one that will start, will block the others.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
```

Try this.